# Memory alignment mask in dlmalloc

Tags: c, memory

I was reading up on Doug Lea's memory allocator [here](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c). I found the following macros to calculate the offset to be added to an address to make it aligned.

```
/* The bit mask value corresponding to MALLOC_ALIGNMENT */
#define CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK    (MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - SIZE_T_ONE)

/* True if address a has acceptable alignment */
#define is_aligned(A)       (((size_t)((A)) & (CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)) == 0)

/* the number of bytes to offset an address to align it */
#define align_offset(A)\
 ((((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK) == 0)? 0 :\
  ((MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - ((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK))
```

My question is about the last `& CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK`. Why do that?

When `MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - ((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)` is done, you already get how distant the address is from the alignment boundary. Why do an `AND` with the mask again?

Comment: what is `SIZE_T_ONE`? Depending on that, the code you are asking about might not be redundant.  E.g. if `X` is `16 - (7 & 3)`, then `X != (X & 3)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not needed.  Look like [belt and suspenders](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belt_and_suspenders) code.

The following can only take on the values of `[0...CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK]`.  The `& CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK` does not affect the result.

```
((((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK) == 0)? 0 :\
    ((MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - ((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)) ...))
```

It would be better to use only 1 evaluation of `A` with the following.  IN this case, the 2nd `& CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK` is needed to handle the aligned case:

```
#define align_offset(A) \
  ((MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - ((size_t)(A) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)) & CHUNK_ALIGN_MASK)
```